Is there a way to show nature change only via `nx show projects --affected`
I am using nx to manage a monorepo and one of the feature offered from nx is nx show projects --affected which gives me the affected apps based on the change I made in a PR.
For example, if there are two packages A and B and A depends on B. If I change B, both A and B will be shown from nx show projects --affected command. It is great to run necessary build on affected packages.
But I have a requirement to auto generate messages about what projects are changed from a PR. In this case, I don't want to include both A and B. Is there a way to only show the nature change from nx command to exclude dependent changes?
The only solution I have is to use git diff to show it but it is a bit complicated in the shell command. Is there something can get from nx out of the box?
